# update_attributes with transient Rspec/FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am looking to find out if it is possible to update an objects attributes with a transient value, I have this test

```
it 'should be able to update an image category' do
  @image = FactoryGirl.create(:image, categories_count: 2)
  expect(@image.image_categories.count).to eq(2)
  @image.update_attributes(categories_count: 1)
  @image.save
  expect(@image.image_categories.count).to eq(1)
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    title 'Test Title'
    description 'Test Description'
    transient do
      photo_name 'validated_image.jpg'
    end
    photo { File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec/fixtures', photo_name)) }
    transient do
      categories_count 1
    end
    categories { build_list(:category, categories_count) }
  end
end
```

But it fails with

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
unknown attribute 'categories_count' for Image.
```

How would i go about updating the categories_count for `@image`

Schema

```
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "photo_file_name"
  t.string   "photo_content_type"
  t.integer  "photo_file_size"
  t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "image_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "image_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

Models

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
  has_attached_file :photo,
                styles: {
                  image_square_home: '350x350#',
                  image_thumb: '100x100#'
                }
  validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'], message: 'Images must be jpg/jpeg/gif/png format only' },
                           size: { in: 0..2000.kilobytes, message: 'Images should be less than 2 megabytes' }
  validates :title, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a title" }
  validates :description, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a description" }
  validates :categories, presence: { message: 'Choose At Least 1 Category' }
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
  validates :name, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a Category" }
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, message: 'Category name %{value} already exists'
  validates_format_of :name, with: /\A([A-Za-z]+ )+[A-Za-z]+$|^[A-Za-z]+\z/, message: 'Only A-Z Characters Allowed', allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

When running the test i get the following output

```
 Failure/Error: @image.update_attributes(categories_count: 1)

 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
   unknown attribute 'categories_count' for Image.
 # ./spec/models/image_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # NoMethodError:
 #   undefined method `categories_count=' for #<Image:0x00000005483550>
 #   ./spec/models/image_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Could you add your database schema and the `image` and `category` models please.

Comment: @Tobias updated, thanks

Comment: I would like to have tests that check that a `categories_count` can be updated, as a image can have many categories, so i need to be able to remove and add

Comment: @Richlewis - could you post your entire image factory?

Comment: @BroiSatse updated, thanks

Comment: @Richlewis - I am not entirely sure, but I think you cannot have multiple `transient` block in a single factory. Can you try moving both definition to a single block and check if that works? In the meantime I will search the FactoryGirl source code.

Comment: @Richlewis - curiouser and curiouser. According to the source it should be ok to have two `transient` blocks. Could you also paste the error stack trace?

Comment: thanks for looking into this, give me 5 mins and i will get that for you

Comment: @BroiSatse I have updated the question with the error that is output, is that what you required ?

Comment: @Richlewis what are you trying to do here? If you want to have an Image with multiple categories, add them through the association. There is no `categories_count` attribute.

Comment: @zetetic I am trying to update the `categories`, so when the object was created it had 2 categories associated to it, with `update attributes` or `update_attribute` as only changing 1 I would like to make that 1 associated category. I know that `categories_count` is not an attribute, its my transient alias i guess which i set in the FactoryGirl Object, I just thought that I could update the `categories_count` in the same way I created it

Answer (score 3):

Was looking into a wrong line all the time. Your factory is fine and you use it the right way. Factory returns an ActiveRecord object, which has no idea about how it was created and has absolutely no knowledge about how its factory has been generated:

```
@image.update_attributes(categories_count: 1)
```

`update_attributes` acts on the record itself, which has no idea about `categories_count`. It is also not clear what you want here to happen or what you are actually testing as looks you are testing FactoryGirl rather than your model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What im trying to test is that I can update the categories for my `@image` object. so when created it had 2, now i want to make it 1 for example.. how can i do that ?